Why does adding parentheses remove 'readonly [x: number]: number;' from this type?
enum Animals {
  CAT,
  DOG,
  PARROT,
  SHEEP,
  SALMON
}

The following type:
type AnimalsToMappedType = {
  [K in keyof typeof Animals]: K
}

Results in:
type AnimalsToMappedType = {
  readonly [x: number]: number;
  readonly CAT: "CAT";
  readonly DOG: "DOG";
  readonly PARROT: "PARROT";
  readonly SHEEP: "SHEEP";
  readonly SALMON: "SALMON";
}

But if you add parentheses around keyof typeof Animals:
type AnimalsToMappedType = {
  [K in (keyof typeof Animals)]: K
}

The result is:
type AnimalsToMappedType = {
    CAT: "CAT";
    DOG: "DOG";
    PARROT: "PARROT";
    SHEEP: "SHEEP";
    SALMON: "SALMON";
}

QUESTION
What are the parentheses doing that removes readonly [x: number]: number;?

Please [edit] to clearly ask a single, well-defined question. Right now this looks like multiple questions, much of which looks like an XY problem since you have some underlying use case (writing a mapped type) and your questions are about your failed attempts. If you're asking about the underlying use case, I'd say write { [K in string & keyof typeof Animals as typeof Animals[K]]: K }. If you're asking about the behavior of your attempts, please ask just one question about one such attempt and break out the rest into their own questions if they remain after getting this one answered.

@jcalz it was a lot clearer before someone decided to take it upon themselves to edit it

Hmm, I still see multiple questions in there. Which one is your primary question?

Thanks. Without the parens it's a homomorphic mapped type, where TS recognizes that you're iterating over "all the properties of typeof Animals"; in some sense in keyof is its own syntactic unit. With the parentheses it is not homomorphic and just iterates over whatever keys are in the expression.  Numeric enum objects have reverse mappings in their type (and a numeric index signature), but number is not included in keyof typeof Animals. Hence the difference. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write a full a; if not, what's missing?

(see prev comment...https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40206 is the canonical issue for this, btw, I'll include that in my answer if you agree that it fully addresses the question)

See microsoft/TypeScript#40206 for an authoritative answer.
A mapped type of the form {[K in keyof XXX]: YYY} is considered a homomorphic mapped type, where TypeScript sees in keyof and recognizes that you're transforming some other type XXX, and can therefore use information about the original type that isn't present in the results of keyof. On the other hand, a mapped type of the similar form {[K in (keyof XXX)]: YYY} is not considered homomorphic. The parentheses cause TypeScript to first compute keyof XXX, and then the mapped types iterates over these results without knowing or remembering anything about XXX.  So in keyof XXX keeps information about XXX around that in (keyof XXX) discards.
This difference is most commonly seen when transforming a type with optional and readonly properties. A homomorphic mapped type will preserve the optional/readonly, even though such information is not visible via keyof.  For example, if XXX is {a?: string, readonly b: number} then {[K in keyof XXX]: YYY} will produce {a?: YYY, readonly b: YYY}, whereas {[K in (keyof XXX): YYY} will produce {a: YYY, b: YYY}.
In your example, you're operating on a numeric enum object, which has reverse mappings. If Animals.CAT === 0 then Animals[0] === "CAT". TypeScript models this by adding a numeric index signature to the enum object, but this index signature is suppressed when you use keyof.  So while typeof Animals might look like { [k: number]: string; CAT: 0 }, keyof typeof Animals is just "CAT" and not number | "CAT". So a homomorphic mapped type over a numeric enum will have a numeric index signature, whereas a non-homomorphic mapped type over keyof a numeric enum will not.
